# Accessing a network path and coverting it to a File path using Java

Tags: java, java-8, file-handling

I have a network path which looks like this:

```
\\rennas01\\test\Project\\InputFiles
```

I need to use this network path as a abstract path for my File instance:

```
File src=new File(path);
```

How can I use this network path to look something like:

```
File src=new File("\\\\rennas01\\test\\Project\\InputFiles")
```

As it is a path to a network shared driver. File will not accept it as a correct parameter.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Lino  This won't work "\\rennas01\\test\\Project\\InputFiles" is a path to a shared drive on a network. File will not consider it as a correct parameter.

Comment: @matrix_hsi do you really need that it looks like `new File("\\rennas01\\test\\Project\\InputFiles")`? it should work as `new File("\\\\rennas01\\test\\Project\\InputFiles")` assuming `rennas01` is known and accessible

Answer (score 2):

In your example you escaped every backslash but you have forgotten the one at the beginning of the path:

```
// this path points to wrong location: \rennas01\test\Project\InputFiles
File src=new File("\\rennas01\<test\\Project\\InputFiles");
```

should actually be:

```
// this path points to desired location: \\rennas01\test\Project\InputFiles
File src=new File("\\\\rennas01\\test\\Project\\InputFiles");
```

This small correction should solve your problem.

Comment: This won't work. I need a solution around the concepts of URL and URI.
It doesn't matter how many backslash I give or skip. It won't work.
Java File object accepts only actual file paths.

It is a shared path on a network drive.

Comment: @matrix_hsi File accepts shared path on a network drive, for example, the following works perfectly on my system `File f = new File("\\\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\jre\\test\\out_9.log"); 
System.out.println("Length using f.length() : " + f.length()); ` where xx.xx.xx.xx is the IP of the remote machine. May be you should elaborate your question some more.

Comment: You can also take a look at the  `java.nio.file` package. `Paths.get` method takes both `String` path and `URI`. Besides, a `Path` can be converted to `File` using `toFile()` method , if your code only accepts `File`.